# When dealing with soil mixture and compost ratios, are you supposed to go by volume or weight?

Tags: soil, soil-amendment

I found what looks like a good raised vegetable garden soil mixture: 1/3 top soil, 1/3 compost manure, and 1/3 peat moss. Should I go by weight or volume?

Comment: Could you add more information to your question, and be more specific? Where did you find the information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *good* recipe will tell you whether the author means weight or volume...

In this case I'd assume volume, since topsoil is so much heavier than peat moss: if you mix equal weights, you'll have way too much peat moss.

Also, note that peat moss can be acidic. I'd recommend performing a pH test on both your topsoil and peat moss. If they are acidic, add lime as your building the beds to bring pH up to around 6-6.5 (assuming the raised beds are for a "typical" mix of vegetables; other plantings may have very different needs).

Answer (score 5):

A formula like this, unless specified otherwise,  is (ok, *almost*) always by volume.